# A paper that proves using the latent features of RBM as input to logistic regression?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, scikit-learn, deep-learning, deep-belief-networks

I'm looking for a paper that includes a proof that simply training a Restricted Boltzmann Machine and then using the latent features as input to a logistic regression classifier is a correct thing and makes sense.

The thing is that I know that training deep belief networks is done in a different way than the described procedure I mentioned above. Since the training involves pretraining, fine-tuning and then using a Softmax function. However, this tutorial from `scikit-learn` is merely using the procedure I described: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_rbm_logistic_classification.html

I'm looking for a paper that justifies the procedure in the tutorial. Or at least that justifies that the latent features of a Restricted Boltzmann Machine are better than the original features.

Comment: Take a look at the following two papers, which, I hope, are relevant to the topic: [this](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/3078-modeling-human-motion-using-binary-latent-variables.pdf) and [this](http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/icml2007_SalakhutdinovMH07.pdf).

Comment: This is a good one comparing logistic regression and DBNs: Bengio, et al. (2007). [Greedy Layer-Wise Training of Deep Networks](https://web.archive.org/web/20160617185344/http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lisa/publications2/index.php/publications/show/190).